# Django Rest Framework: View That Supports Arbitrary HTTP verbs?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is there a view type that will, for example allow me to both:

GET `/account/items`

and

POST / PATCH `account/items/<pk>/` all in one go? From one Viewset or something? Note that I am not creating anything on the `account/items` route on POST– but I need to POST to `account/items/<pk>` to perform a specific action

As far as I can tell, I would need to make two separate views, one for getting the list via `GET /account/items` and one for doing custom POST and PATCH operations on a detail view. Is that right?

Comment: Isn't this how Viewsets work? Maybe I don't understand your question but take a look at the @action decorator: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#introspecting-viewset-actions , you can set the "detail" variable which handles if it uses the list or detail url.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that– it doesn't look like I can get the exact url scheme I want using that. The @action decorator takes the function name as the next part of the url path, but I want to have it be the pk. On the other hand, it doesn't seem like the regular detail views in a Viewset allow me to override POST like that on a detail route (I need to get the pk from the path).

Answer (score 0):

You should use DRF’s [class-based views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#class-based-views).

> Using the APIView class is pretty much the same as using a regular View class, as usual, the incoming request is dispatched to an appropriate handler method such as .get() or .post().

Here's an example with a `get` and `post` handler. I've abstracted the code for updating a user into a helper method for you to create - your implementation will vary:

```py
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from my_project.accounts.helpers import update_user

class UserView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Return a user.
        """
        user_data = User.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk']).values()
        return Response(user_data)

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = User.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
        data = request.POST
        update_user(user, data)
        return Response('Updated user!')
```

You may also want to look into [ViewSets](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/), which provide easy CRUD operation handling.

Comment: So I'm using an APIView right now– I know that this covers the GET `account/items` case, but this `POST` in your example above doesn't seem to cover POSTing to `account/items/<PK>` to perform an action.

Comment: That particular APIView example (from the documentation) is for a list view, but you can point any url to any APIView. You could create a `User` view that returned a single user in its `get` method, created a user in its `post` method, and updated a user in its `patch` method. Do this just like you would in any other view. I can update my answer with an example if it would be helpful.

Comment: I went ahead and modified my answer. Let me know if this makes sense now.

Comment: If a request comes to any verb, not supported you don't get a 405 like in function-based, views, instead you get a 500 expected a Response got a NoneType error.